# Adding files to the bin directory at Build and Publish

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two license files that I would like to include in my `\bin` directory both when I build *and* publish.

Both files are in the `App_Data` directory (their initial location doesn't matter, they just need to end up in the `\bin`) and have the following properties set:

- `Build Action` = `Content`
- `Copy to Output Directory` = `Copy Always`

They are in not the `\bin` when I build or publish.

What is wrong with my setup: the settings, the folders, the files, something else...?

**UPDATE**

I moved the files out of the App_Data directory and placed them in the project root and now they are copied to the `\bin` on build.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've done this in a few projects by expanding my .csproject file slightly. The following code should be put directly beneath the `Project` node in your WebProject.csproj.
The `AfterBuild` target simply copies a set of files ("unreferenced DLLs" in this case) to the bin-folder when building normally from Visual Studio. The CustomCollectFiles basically do the same thing when deploying.

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <UnreferencedDlls>..\lib\Unreferenced\**\*.dll</UnreferencedDlls>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
      CustomCollectFiles;
      $(CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn);
    </CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <Message Text="Copying unreferenced DLLs to bin" Importance="High" />
    <CreateItem Include="$(UnreferencedDlls)">
      <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="_UnReferencedDLLs" />
    </CreateItem>
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(_UnReferencedDLLs)" DestinationFolder="bin\%(RecursiveDir)" SkipUnchangedFiles="true" />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="CustomCollectFiles">
    <Message Text="Publishing unreferenced DLLs" Importance="High" />
    <ItemGroup>
      <_CustomFiles Include="$(UnreferencedDlls)" />
      <FilesForPackagingFromProject Include="%(_CustomFiles.Identity)">
        <DestinationRelativePath>bin\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</DestinationRelativePath>
      </FilesForPackagingFromProject>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

The part you need to modify is basically the `UnreferencedDlls` node to match your folder structure. The `**\*.dll` part simply means "every DLL file at any level beneath here".

Comment: Sounds viable - I'll try it out

Comment: I added this, but it didn't appear to do anything.

Comment: Reading this a little closer, I think that this will only work when I have the "Copy Always" option right? Seems like that option will copy it to the bin folder inside of a folder and this will then put the files directly in the bin folder, is that right?

Comment: It should simply be copying every file in the UnreferencedDlls-path into bin when publishing. There should not be any more levels of folders than what you put there yourself. For instance, if all your DLLs that you want to copy resides in ..\lib\Unreferenced\, they will end up in bin/. If you have them in ..\lib\Unreferenced\SomeFolder\ they wil end up in bin\SomeFolder\. Did that make sense? :-)

Answer (score 11):

If you're using **Visual Studio**:

- Show your file properties (*Click* on your file or *Right-click* on it then choose *Properties*)
- At the **Copy to Output Directory** property choose **Copy always** or **Copy if newer**.

At build time, the file is going to be copied at the bin directory: Debug or Release...

Comment: In VS2022/NET7 this doesn't copy to Publish directory as-is, but it's an easy fix: manually edit csproj to add `CopyToPublishDirectory` just like the `CopyToOutputDirectory` that VS creates for us.

Answer (score 0):

not necessarily a direct answer, but I highly suggest not using the baked in "publish" mechanism, but rather wire up a build script (probably in powershell) that will do everything you need. It's really easy to hook into MSBuild as well as nUnit and also copy files and move them around.

POWERSHELL (rough) example.

```
# Get Directory Location
$invocation = (Get-Variable MyInvocation).Value
$directorypath = Split-Path $invocation.MyCommand.Path

# Build the application using MSBuild
cmd /c C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\$v4_net_version\msbuild.exe "$directorypath\MyProject.sln" /p:Configuration=Release 

# Run the tests using nUnit
cmd /c $directorypath\build\nunit\nunit-console.exe $solutionPath\MyProject.Tests\bin\debug\MyProject.Tests.dll

# Copy the license to the appropriate directory
Copy-Item -LiteralPath "$directorypath\mylicensefile.txt" "$directorypath\bin\release" -Force 

# NOTE: You are going to have to adjust this to match your solution and projects.
```

Comment: I get what your saying, but we already have a pretty established workflow. I can see why we should perhaps consider moving towards something like this.

Answer (score 0):

In this post on Microsoft Connect the answer is much simpler:
[Referenced assemblies in Unit Test are not copied in TestResults/Out](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/533935/referenced-assemblies-in-unit-test-are-not-copied-in-testresults-out)

So what I did was the following:

```
[TestClass]
[DeploymentItem("Some.dll")]
public class SomeTests
{
...
}
```

It works fine for me.
Hope it help.