# Publish unreferenced files to Debug or Release folder

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2022

I use this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18111943/524861) to copy unreferenced files. The answer shown copies the files directly into the `bin` folder and not in either the `Debug` or `Release` folder.

How do I modify the answer to copy to the correct folder? Also, will publishing as a ClickOnce application publish the unreferenced files?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the hardcoded `bin` value to `$(OutputPath)`