# How to publish file from subfolder to main application folder?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, clickonce, .net-4.8

I have a WinForms NET4.8 desktop app that I publish using ClickOnce. I have a dll file in a project subfolder that I need published to the same directory as the main app. I have the following in my csproj file:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <UnreferencedDlls>lib\twaindsm.dll</UnreferencedDlls>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
            CustomCollectFiles;
            $(CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn);
        </CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <Message Text="Copying unreferenced DLLs to bin" Importance="High" />
    <CreateItem Include="$(UnreferencedDlls)">
      <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="_UnReferencedDLLs" />
    </CreateItem>
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(_UnReferencedDLLs)" DestinationFolder="$(OutputPath)\%(RecursiveDir)" SkipUnchangedFiles="true" />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="CustomCollectFiles">
    <Message Text="Publishing unreferenced DLLs" Importance="High" />
    <ItemGroup>
      <_CustomFiles Include="$(UnreferencedDlls)" />
      <FilesForPackagingFromProject Include="%(_CustomFiles.Identity)">
        <DestinationRelativePath>$(OutputPath)\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</DestinationRelativePath>
      </FilesForPackagingFromProject>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

The file is published to the subfolder.

I change this line:

```
<DestinationRelativePath>$(OutputPath)\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</DestinationRelativePath>
```

to:

```
<DestinationRelativePath>$(OutputPath)\%(Filename)%(Extension)</DestinationRelativePath>
```

But it still doesn't work.

How can I force the file to be published to the same folder as the app?

Comment: Did you check the output window for if done the target "CustomCollectFiles"? Maybe you can add an AfterTargets="AfterBuild" after the CustomCollectFiles target like this : <Target Name="CustomCollectFiles" AfterTargets="AfterBuild">. And where do you want to put the unreferenced DLL. In publish folder or bin folder?

Comment: When I build, the DLL is placed in bin\lib. When I publish it is also placed in .\lib. I need the DLL placed in the same folder as as the main EXE so that it is found at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it can help you: [%(RecursiveDir)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-well-known-item-metadata?view=vs-2022)

> If the Include attribute contains the wildcard **, this metadata
> specifies the part of the path that replaces the wildcard.

Maybe you can try to change the path of the dll. I put it into `ProjectDir\lib\Debug\` and here is my code:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <UnreferencedDlls>lib\**\ClassLibrary1.dll</UnreferencedDlls>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup>
  <CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
        CustomCollectFiles;
        $(CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn);
    </CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
</PropertyGroup>
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
  <Message Text="Copying unreferenced DLLs to bin" Importance="High" />
  <CreateItem Include="$(UnreferencedDlls)">
     <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="_UnReferencedDLLs" />
  </CreateItem>
  <Copy SourceFiles="@(_UnReferencedDLLs)" DestinationFolder="bin\%(RecursiveDir)" SkipUnchangedFiles="true" />
</Target>
<Target Name="CustomCollectFiles">
  <Message Text="Publishing unreferenced DLLs" Importance="High" />
  <ItemGroup>
    <_CustomFiles Include="$(UnreferencedDlls)" />
    <FilesForPackagingFromProject Include="%(_CustomFiles.Identity)">
      <DestinationRelativePath>bin\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</DestinationRelativePath>
    </FilesForPackagingFromProject>
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

You can also refer to [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18111401/adding-files-to-the-bin-directory-at-build-and-publish) hope it can help you.